# How to adjust DST value for a particular date for any given timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, timezone, dst

I am writing an astrology app in javascript. I want to adjust DST values for a date which the user has entered for their selected timezone.
I have written following code in javascript which gives me a difference between 2 dates & accordingly am considering the value

```
var utcoff = moment.tz(data.custtz).utcOffset();
//var newdst = moment(new Date()).utcOffset();

//var x = new Date();
//var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

var janOffset = moment.tz({month: 0, day: 1}, data.custtz).utcOffset();
var junOffset = moment.tz({month: 5, day: 1}, data.custtz).utcOffset();
var nwoff =  Math.abs(junOffset - janOffset);

if(nwoff > 0){
    utcoff = nwoff
}
```

This code works for most of the positive timezones but it fails for negative timezones

Comment: See if moment.js has something built-in for this.

Comment: Hi.  You said you want to adjust values for a date the user has entered, but you aren't showing any of that here.  Please edit your question to match what you are trying to accomplish.  See also [What is the "XY Problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201534).

Comment: Note that Moment + Moment-Timezone has all the functionality you need to achieve your stated goal built-in.  You do not need to calculate offsets or adjust for DST yourself.